# Lock object based on a condition in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

I need to lock a piece of code based on the value of a variable or a property. Assume my method is being called and pass UserData object.

```
UserData contains two properties 

UserID and Marks
```

And the lock code currently is like

```
var l=new Object();
lock(l)
{
//Update marks of a particualr user id to UserData.Marks
}
```

Now it'll lock everything that comes for this method, Say it is updating marks of UserID=1, it'll still lock the future calls of other User IDs, I want it to lock requests for that particular user id which is accessing the lock, in this Case User 1. Other should move freely.

What I was thinking that rather create an new object for locking, create a custom class for lock which contains the property of User ID. When the request comes I create a lock based on that particular value. I don't even know if this is possible. Kindly guide me in correct direction.

Comment: You should not create a locking object like this. If this method is used by more threads, every one of them will create an object for locking and synchronization won't work. Use `static readonly object locker = new object();` instead in your class.

Comment: What types are Id and Marks?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek `locker` has to be static only when synchronizing static members for instance members it has to be a instance variable. otherwise unwanted synchronization will happen between two independent instances

Comment: @HenkHolterman Id and Marks are of type int.

Comment: UserID, user id, User ID, and User.  Be precise.  Show the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are currently locking would not do anything at all as two threads calling the function would create two seperate lock objects, however you stated "*Assume my method is being called and pass UserData object.*" and also that each `UserData` object just has the two properties of `Id` and `Marks`

If that is true, all you need to do is lock on that `UserData` object.

```
public void UpdateMarks(UserData userData)
{
    lock(userData)
    {
         //Do stuff to userData.Marks
    }
}
```

The only thing to be aware of is if you have further locks inside that code that could depend on other lock objects you could get your self in to a deadlocked situation.

Comment: From your answer I have a thought in my mind, I don't know if it is right or wrong. It it possible that before lock statement, I could create a new object and set UserData.ID to it and then use that object as a lock. It might helps me the purpose of having a lock on similar IDs, because I lock the whole UserData object, I know marks are always going to be different, so it'll probably create a new lock all the time.